# Wordpress Theme Suggestion

Tags: wordpress, themes, blogs

I would like to display a wordpress blog in the following fashion:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/

Like you can expand the categories and articles.

Any suggestions regarding themes for achieving this? Or should I write my own? I would not like to maintain it, so I am a bit afraid of writing my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the cool stuff there is Javascript that does the animations and interactive elements that won't be anything standard on a WordPress standard theme.

**BUT,**

A quick google search for "**knowledge base themes wordpress**" sould turn up some interesting results. (Like [this one](http://themeforest.net/item/sofa-qanda-knowledge-base-wp-theme/180802?ref=foxinni))

Otherwise you will have to code it all up yourself or hire someone.